# How many steps does jQuery animate in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, algorithm, animation

I'm writing my own animate function for fun and stuff.

I can't really get a smooth animation to occur though. jQuery has an awesome ratio of steps per animation making it really smooth, I was wondering what is the general formula they use to figure out how many steps to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the duration of the animation. jQuery, using its default setting stored in `jQuery.fx.interval`, starts a single 13 ms interval timer common to all animations when the first one is started and stops it once all have completed.

Search for `animate:`, `custom:`, `interval:`, and `step:` in the [unminified jQuery source code](http://bit.ly/jquery-source). The last of these contains the logic that determines the fraction of the animation that has already run, which is based on timestamps: `new Date().getTime()` in pure JS.

This theoretically yields about 80 frames/s, faster than the 60 Hz refresh rate of most of today's LCD monitors. You could probably get by with dropping the frame rate a bit (increasing the interval) if performance is a problem.