# Why does a CSS transition not work well with another animation based on jQuery's animate method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that I wish to move when it is clicked, and while moving it should also flip. So there are two animations that take place at the same time, and have the same duration. I also have a CSS `transition` set up for all the properties of the button. It seems to me that only the CSS scale transform works when I use both jQuery's `animate` method and the CSS transition effect. When I remove one of the animations, the other one works well.

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button");

// handle click
button.on("click", function() {
  button.css({
    "transform": "scaleX(0)"
  });
  
 // the bug: the following animation is not visible
  button.animate({
    "top": "-100px" // I tried without "px" too
  }, 0.15 * 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

The JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/silviubogan/w6sx3r5c/).

Thank you.

Comment: you need an initial value in the CSS `top:0`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tested your solution in the fiddle and it still does not work for me.

Comment: by the way, why you need animate since you are consider transition? make both inside css()

Comment: Any reason your not doing both in CSS, because using jQuery will loose hardware acceleration features.  `"scaleX(0) translate(0, -100px)"`

Comment: @Keith I solved the problem using just CSS but I was still wandering why the old way does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your button style as `transition: all 0.15s;` that is affecting the `top` property too. Therefore, in your flow:

1. The top animation does happen a few ms after the css manipulation
2. Every step of the top animation is subject to a transition

Due to the first, there's already a racing condition that may cause the top animation to go unnnoticed, but due to the second, there's also an easing over every step of jQuery's animation.

If not provided, [$.fn.animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) easing function defaults to `swing` which is defined as:

```
 function( p ) {
    return 0.5 - Math.cos( p * Math.PI ) / 2;
 }
```

Where `p` is between 0 and 1.

In this case, you're asking jQuery to change `top` from 0 to -100 in 150ms. Usually the animation interval [is around 13ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543279/how-many-steps-does-jquery-animate-in), but let's say it's exactly 15ms so we have **10 animation steps**. Due to the `swing` easing, the first step amounts for:

```
 100 * (0.5 -  Math.cos( (0.1 * Math.PI ) / 2) = 2.45
```

In other words, due to `transition: all 0.15s` and leaving the race condition apart, clicking the button **would scale it horizontally to 0 and move it 2.45px upwards in 0.15s**.

If, instead, you only transition the `transform` property, and leave the `top` transition to jQuery, you could see both of them happening in parallel.

In the following snippet I slowed things down to take 1s, added console statements on each step and included the regular button, another one that only transitions `transform` and a third one that transitions `transform` and `top` which doesn't use jQuery animations.

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button.animate");

// handle click
button.on("click", function() {
  console.clear();

  $(this).css(
    "transform", (index, value) => {
      console.log(`top: transform was ${value}`);
      return "scaleX(0)";
    }
  );

  console.log('before $.fn.animate');
  $(this).animate({
    "top": "-100px"
  }, 1000, 'swing', () => {
    console.log('finish animation');
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('restore initial state')
      $(this).css({
        transform: "unset",
        top: 0
      });
    }, 2000);
  });



});

// handle click
$("button.no_animate").on("click", function() {
  console.clear();

  $(this).css({
    "transform": "scaleX(0)",
    "top": "-100px"
  });

  window.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('restore everything');
    $(this).css({
      transform: "unset",
      top: 0
    });
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

button.animate.all {
  transition: all 1s;
}

button.animate.transform {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

button.no_animate {
  top: 0;
  transition: top 1s, transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="check">Hello World</p>
  <button class="animate all">I Transition all</button>
  <button class="animate transform">I Transition "transform" </button>
  <button class="no_animate transform">I don't use animate </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use only the required property in `transition` i.e. `transform 0.15s` instead of `all 0.15s`

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button");

// handle click
button.on("click", function() {
  button.css({
    "transform": "scaleX(0)"
  });

  // the bug: the following animation is not visible
  button.animate({
    "top": "-100px" // I tried without "px" too
  }, 0.15 * 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;

  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.15s; /* change here*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please see the code on JS fiddle for smooth animation:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/harshsetia/tvcb4mso/8/

Answer (score -1):

your button position should bet set to absolute!

```js
var button = $("button");

// handle click
button.on("click", function() {
  button.css({
    "transform": "scaleX(0)"
  });

    // the bug: the following animation is not visible
  button.animate({top: "-100px"}, 0.15 * 1000);
});
```

```css
button{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```